# Without Doubt , Firmly

Tags: difference

I have a question about the usage of "*firmly*".  If I write these two sentences, one using "*without doubt*" and one using "*firmly*":

> 1. The experiment was ***without doubt*** successful.
> 2. The experiment was ***firmly*** successful.

Are sentences 1 and 2 truly the same?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 can be adjusted using these words:

**without a doubt**
OR
**undoubtedly**

Since the experiment is successful, there is no issue with it in terms of complications and firmly doesn't capture that sense.

Sentence 2: Firmly usually refers to things held in place or it can be used metaphorically to describe thoughts or actions that are strong and unyielding as opposed to loose and weak.

For example:

> The cat firmly gripped the mouse.